# How can i toast when parsing object is not present in that parsing link?

Tags: android, android-json

I had done parsing using volley.
What I just need is that when i parse any object like `movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));` and there is no object name in that link there should be a toast.
here is my present code of parsing

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            hidePDialog();
                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                        movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                .doubleValue());
                        movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                        // Genre is json array
                        JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                        ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                            genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                        }
                        movie.setGenre(genre);

                        // adding movie to movies array
                        movieList.add(movie);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the Context instance for Toast.

```
if (obj.has("title")) 
  movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
else Toast.makeText(....).show();
```

**EDITED**

mapping maybe NULL, so use isNull:

```
if (!obj.isNull("title")) 
   movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title")); 
else Toast.makeText(....).show();
```

Comment: Try obj.isNull("title").

Comment: where to use this. can you please explain with a example

Comment: if (!obj.isNull("title")) 
  movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
else Toast.makeText(....).show();

Comment: And what is the result of obj.isNull("title")? Is it always true or false? What exactly does not work.